# Counting files contained in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

How can I count all files, hidden files, directories, hidden directories, sub-directories, hidden sub-directories and (symbolic) links in a given directory using bash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find . | wc -l
```

This will count each symlink as a file.  To traverse symlinks, counting their contents, use:

```
find -L . | wc -l
```

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -print0 | tr -cd '\0' | wc -c
```

This handles filenames with newline characters.

Comment: never seen such file, but your answer is interesting... +1

Answer (score 2):

This does it:

```
find the_directory|wc -l
```

This works be finding all files in the directory, and counting them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
tree
```

it gives you a count in the end. I don't know how the speed compares with find. Lazily:

```
tree | tail -1
```

easier to type than find :-)